# Run JavaFX 11 on IDE cause URL not found error on ressource from submodule

Tags: java, javafx, java-11

I'm migrating my application from JavaFX 8 to JavaFx 11.

When I built my application with maven is mostly OK. 
But I cannot run my application in IntelliJ. I recieved :

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.service.ConfigurationManager.configureDefaultImageSim(ConfigurationManager.java:79)
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.service.ConfigurationManager.<init>(ConfigurationManager.java:65)
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.service.ConfigurationManager.<clinit>(ConfigurationManager.java:36)
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.service.ProjectFileManager.<init>(ProjectFileManager.java:33)
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.service.ProjectFileManager.<clinit>(ProjectFileManager.java:31)
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.service.ApplicationManager.<init>(ApplicationManager.java:31)
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.service.ApplicationManager.<clinit>(ApplicationManager.java:28)
    at simtree.client.desktop/simtree.client.SimTreeRun.start(SimTreeRun.java:11)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1107)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:617)
    at simtree.visualization.vanilla/simtree.visualization.controls.skineables.SimPhoto.<clinit>(SimPhoto.java:39)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1099)
    ... 19 more
```

Files where point URL are in ressource folder in module beeing dependency form my client desktop module.
Why those files wasn't exported while building application ? How shoul I configure this ?

https://gitlab.com/mszymkowiak/simtree

Comment: *Invalid URL or resource not found* ... can you share relevant code to this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code or setup. When you say you run from IntelliJ, do you use the Maven window, to run `exec`? Did you run `compile` plugin first? That should copy the resources.

Comment: I've added link to my gitlab simtree-java11migration branch.